# check hosting type of a domain

Tags: domain

how do i know whether my hosting domain is shared or dedicated

Comment: By pricing, resources available, access to the machine, etc.

Comment: Ask your ISP how you are setup.

Comment: Not knowing how you are hosted is asking for trouble.  The default assumption is probably that you are on shared hosting unless you have specifically requested and paid extra.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact your hosting provider, and ask the question to them. You would be unaware of wether you have shared or dedicated hosting.
What your paying is a very good indication though.